# ORACLE SQL Creating Update Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Hey all so I am trying to create a trigger that will Update values in a table when they fall below a certain value.

For example say I have table Inventory:

```
Item | Quantity
-----|---------
A    |      400
B    |      160
C    |     1200
D    |      105
```

I want to make a trigger that will add a random value(100 - 200) if Quantity of an item should ever drop below 100.

This is what I have come up with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER QuantityTrigger
AFTER
UPDATE ON INVENTORY FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF :QUANTITY < 100 THEN
   UPDATE INVENTORY
   SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY + dbms_random.value(100,200);
 END IF;
END;
```

However this gives me error: `Error(2,9): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'QUANTITY'`

What am I doing wrong? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: remove the : in front of QUANTITY in the IF clause, oracle thinks it as an input (bind) variable

Comment: try :new.quantity instead

Comment: Made the change now it gives me the error: `Error(2,9): PLS-00201: identifier 'QUANTITY' must be declared`

Comment: sorry my bad, try what @Aramillo just said

Comment: Aramillo's change allowed it to compile successfully. Now to test it.

Comment: I tried testing my trigger with `UPDATE INVENTORY
SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY - 1150
WHERE ITEMNAME = 'C';` however it gives me an error `table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Basically it is telling you to not do DML inside a trigger. Check out [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html) and [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2599480800346313755#2600827300346401245)

Comment: That's because you are update the same table which owner the trigger. So why use a trigger, what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Syntax Error: Change `:QtyOnHand` to `:new.QtyOnHand`.

Logic error: Instead of writing an after trigger, change it to a before trigger and only update the column value without doing any UPDATE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER QuantityTrigger
BEFORE
UPDATE ON QITEM FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF :new.QtyOnHand < 100 THEN
   :new.QtyOnHand := :new.QtyOnHand + dbms_random.value(100,200);
 END IF;
END;
/
```

I would however investigate what program inserts values in this table less than 100 and fix that. Using a trigger is a hack by which you are trying to mask a problem's symptoms rather than curing it.

Just use the same logic in the insert statement wherever you suspect values less than 100 are being inserted.

Comment: This code does not work, there is an error with `:new.QtyOnHand = :new.QtyOnHand` it say that it expects '('

Comment: Sorry fixed. The assignment operator is := not =.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the value you are looking for is in:

```
:new.Quantity
```